# How to find all the items that are not numbers in MongoDB collection?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a field in mongodb database that mostly contains numbers, but probably some nulls,  strings, etc as well. How can I find() all these records?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand your question fully. Do you want to get the numbers or the non-numbers? Anyway, here is how you can get either:

The numbers:

`db.stuff.find({my_field: { $type: 1 }})`

The others

`db.stuff.find({my_field: { $not: {$type: 1 }}})`

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`$type`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/type/#_S_type) operator in your query object to select by a field's data type.